# TFS 2015 No agents found when deploying to Azure

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Im trying to set up deployment on my Team Foundation Server 2015.

I set it up to deploy to a Azure website.

But when i check in code and it tries to build i get the following error "No agent could be found with the following capabilities: msbuild, visualstudio, azureps"

I did set up a agent pool and its online.

Hope someone can help

Comment: Why aren't you using the hosted build agent?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install visual studio and azure powershell on your build server.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I just needed to install Visual Studio and it worked.